# How to implement membership subscriptions in Drupal site that is not product based?

Tags: 7

I want to add "***an option to become a member for a certain period of time***" (for short "**membership subscriptions**") to my Drupal site, but I wonder how to do so.

I already used Recurring Subscriptions, which is working fine. But the problem (objection) I have with this solution is that it's based on the **product you have purchased** (which will then confirm your membership).

So I'm looking for a way to implement memberships subscriptions in a Drupal website that is not product based.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @kiamlaluno omg, open up, I was answering the question. It's not too broad...

Comment: @ No Sssweat   give me  any suggestion about this

Comment: you can use a brand new module called [MoneySuite](https://www.drupal.org/project/moneysuite) or [Recurly](https://www.drupal.org/project/recurly)

Comment: thanks but i think its paid any free module is there

Comment: Recurly requires you to pay monthly membership while MoneySuite is 100% free.

Comment: thanks   No Sssweat i think Money Suite  solve my problem

Comment: you only need to enable the Core, Membership Suite and the payment gateway.

Comment: @NoSssweat _I want to add membership on my Drupal site_ **is** to broad, expecially when the OP just say _I tried this module, and it doesn't fit my needs._ Plus, requests for modules are still off-topic.

Comment: @RajBhardwaj : please review my edited version of your (current on hold) question. I tried to address the reasons why it got put on hold, by "*rewording it to fit the rules defined in the help center*" (as suggested at the end of the put-on-hold message box). Please feel free to further enhance (edit) your question where needed, but make sure to not violate the rules (again) that caused your question to be put on hold before. If it ever reaches enough votes to be reopened, then please add an extra comment here to let me know (ping) about that. Good luck!

Comment: Also, please add at least an hyperlink (by editing your question) to the "Recurring Subscriptions" module that you are referring to. I "think" I know what you're talking about, but it helps if anybody who wants to answer it does not have to guess about the question ... Also, this is for D7, rght?